# how to save data on a remote server from an app (jqm+phonegap)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app using jqm+phonegap. In my app, user need to set some parameters and calculate results. Now, i want that at the end of calculation, when the user clicks on a button, all the data (all the settings and calculated results) be saved on a remote server. How can i do that? Please help. Should i write some kind of web service and place that on the server and the button click would invoke this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create some form of interface on the target server, which your application then can use to post and pull data. The most common way to achieve this is to create a SOAP/WSDL webservice. There are libraries and frameworks for PHP, Java and all the other technologies. You can easily use those to create what you need.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without writing a web service?

Comment: I know of no sensible solution that doesn't involve a webservice. How do you suppose the device should be able to communicate with the server? FTP?

Comment: SOAP/WSDL is a total overkill for JQM and mobile devices, and PHP and/or Java "and all the other technologies" is also very broad...

Comment: Of course it's broad...how should I know what possibilities the OP has on his server? And yes...SOAP is pretty heavy, but it's still fairly common. And it was only a suggestion anyway. However, in my experience it pays off to use well established protocols for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

With full respect to the previous answer, there are simpler ways of achieving simple storage (with no server-side processing) of data - whether local or remote (of course only if you do the calculations on the client side and looking only at storing data remotely).

For example, a [CouchDB](http://www.couchbase.org/) solution would allow your client code to directly talk via REST to a DB to store/retrieve/query your data (using Javascript!), in a VERY SIMPLE way - a lot simpler than SOAP/WSDL webservices (and probably faster - one less layer).

Of course there's a learning curve, but I can assure you it's going to be peanuts comparing that to learning SOAP/WSDL/PHP/JAVA. Always pick the right tool for the job.....

First you need to decide WHAT exactly you are trying to achieve, and then start worrying about the HOW.

Just my $.02... Hope this helps

Comment: I fully agree that CouchDB can be a great solution. From the OP it is not apparent, however, what requirements exactly apply to the project and it might just as well be the worst possible solution. ;) The spectrum covered by a standard solution like SOAP is much broader. And with recent rapid development tools (e.g. Spring Roo) it is fairly easy to setup a simple SOAP server. So it really is a question of what exactly is needed.

Comment: agree, that's what last sentence in my answer also asks the OP to do.... first decide WHAT, and then we can pick ideas on HOW ;-)